# How to set with opacity on inactive elements li using jquery carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel

im trying to strive a bit different carousel, id like to have the possibility to change the opacity of inactive elements in the carousel itself.

```
    <section class="wrap">

<div></div>   
</section>    

<section id="carousel">
<ul>
    <li>

            <div class="col">1</div>
            <div class="col">2</div>
            <div class="col">3</div>

    </li>
   <li>

            <div class="col">4</div>
            <div class="col">5</div>
            <div class="col">6</div>

    </li>
    <li>



 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#carousel ul").jcarousel({
        scroll:1,
        auto:5,
        wrap:'both',
        easing: 'easeInOutBack',
        buttonNextHTML: null,
        buttonPrevHTML: null
    });

});​
```

In this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/AntonioCapuozzo/GCJNP/embedded/result/) below there is an example, of what i would like to obtain, starting from the central div. col , let the other elements, the left one and the right one with nearly invisible, is it possible???

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your example link doesn't illustrate what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: id like to se the opacity for the first and last list, showing only the li that is active, scrolling items per 3, for example, 123 ( on the left) invisible, 456 ( the middle ) visible, and the left one invisible, and so on scrolling, a kind of like this: [link](http://synch.wpshower.com) on the Featured videos..

Answer (score 0):

I found an example by the author of the Plugin, I believe it does what you want. You can check out this link :

https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/tree/91b1616fab0e3dfbdb8f39e42f39c48cbe6000d6/examples/feature_slider

// EDIT, You can try this, with some fiddling it should work.

CSS - `.jcarousel-item { opacity : 0.1 } .jcarousel-item.active { opacity: 1 !important }`

JS -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    visible: 3,
    scroll: 1,
    itemVisibleInCallback: {
    onAfterAnimation: function ( c, o, i, s ) {
        i = ( i - 2 ) % $('#mycarousel li').size();
        jQuery('.jcarousel-item').removeClass('active');
        jQuery('.jcarousel-item').eq( i ).addClass('active');
    }
}
});
```

});

​

​

Comment: yes, in a kind of, but it doesn't give me the opacity on the inactives lists

Comment: I think the above should have the desired effect, I've tinkered with it, and it seems to work. However, you still need to add the initial 'active' class when the dom is ready